# Why $wpdb->insert() makes sql syntax error?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using wpdb->insert to insert a row to the table,
like this

```
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array("title"=>"foo"));
```

**$wpdb->last_query** returns the below query

```
INSERT INTO `some_table` (`title`) VALUES ('foo')
```

But i get a error in sql syntax

**WordPress database error:** [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

The error is little confusing, i passed a string 'foo' in to insert statement, but somehow it is showing '1' in the error.

This error occurs when i am running the $wpdb->insert inside phpunit, i copied the query and ran it on my test wordpress database and this query works **correctly in the different method in the same test suite**, it works fine.Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: The second parameter, according to the documentation, has to be an `array` and not a `string`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

Comment: @cabrerahector sorry it was a mistake while writing the question(now edited), and yes i have passed the array to the insert method.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this code. The recommended way (as noted [in codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)):

```
$wpdb->insert($table_name,array('title'=>'foo'),array('%s'));
```